# Working with .po and .mo files translation

Tags: plugins, translation

I translated a plugin with poedit and translation is fine, I checked it changing default language inside general > language. Then I installed Qtranslate-x, it works fine with titles, contents ... but not changing language of other plugins with .po and .mo files. Anybody can help me?